# writing if, elseif and else statements

Tags: php, if-statement

I was wondering if anyone can help me to get this code working...?

```
<?php if (is_front_page() && get_option('of_slider_on_off') == 'true' ) { ?>
<?php require('featured-slider.php'); ?>
<?php }elseif (is_front_page() && get_option('of_slider_on_off') == 'false' ) { ?>
<?php require('featured-countdown.php'); { ?>
<?php }else {
echo '';
}
?>
```

Comment: What is wrong with that code?

Comment: Yeah, someone can help for sure. But the problem is? Anyway, I'll start by avoiding to open and close the php tag at each line, then if those conditions aren't what they're supposed to be we can't tell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php 
if (is_front_page() && get_option('of_slider_on_off') == 'true' ) { 
    require('featured-slider.php'); 
} elseif (is_front_page() && get_option('of_slider_on_off') == 'false' ) { 
    require('featured-countdown.php'); // {
} else {
    echo '';
}
?>
```

You had an extra bracket (commented) that you didn't need. Also no need for the repeated php tags.

If you use a proper IDE with syntax highlighting e.g. [NetBeans](http://netbeans.org/), you will find such problems get underlined in red so you won't get stuck.

Answer (score 6):

What is not working?

As a first step, I would add some indentions and remove the unnecessary PHP start and end tags:

```
<?php
if (is_front_page() && get_option('of_slider_on_off') == 'true' )
{
  require('featured-slider.php');
}
elseif (is_front_page() && get_option('of_slider_on_off') == 'false' )
{
  require('featured-countdown.php');
  {  // Missing curly brace here
}
else
{
  echo '';
}
?>
```